# "Trying to access array offset on value of type null" when using laravel Socialite with function "userFromToken($token)"

Tags: laravel, access-token, facebook-access-token, laravel-socialite

I'm using laravel 8. I'm trying to implement sign in with google option for a mobile application and developing API using laravel Socialite. I don't know how to do this proper way. But I followed [this article](https://j8n.medium.com/laravel-implementing-social-auth-for-api-via-mobile-app-with-socialite-passport-30ff4a6fc4d)

I used google access token and passed using postman.
here is my route

```
Route::get('/customer/login/google', [CustomerAPIController::class,'google']);
```

here is my function as the article given

```
public function google(Request $request) 
    { 
        $provider = "google"; 
        
        $token = $request->input('access_token'); 
        
        $providerUser = Socialite::driver($provider)->userFromToken($token);
        // check if access token exists etc.. 
        
       
        $user = User::where('provider_name', $provider)->where('provider_id', $providerUser->id)->first();
        // if there is no record with these data, create a new user
        if($user == null){
            $user = User::create([
                'provider_name' => $provider,
                'provider_id' => $providerUser->id,
            ]);
        }
        // create a token for the user, so they can login
        $token = $user->createToken(env('APP_NAME'))->accessToken;
        // return the token for usage
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'token' => $token
        ]);
    }
```

But I got this error when passing the access token,

```
"Trying to access array offset on value of type null"
```

I don't know my progress is correct. But I found the issue is coming from this line of the function,

```
 $providerUser = Socialite::driver($provider)->userFromToken($token);
```

What is the wrong in here?  does my whole procedure incorrect.?  how to implement this. IF there is a answer or guide, that would be very helpful.(If the description unclear or if there is missing data please inform)

Comment: Why did not you follow: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/socialite#introduction. Also I am confused on what exactly is that access_token and how are you passing it? Most probably provided on callback right?

Comment: Yes it is.   And also I've got solved my problem there was an issue with the name of "services.php" in my work.  Thanks much